# How to get favicon of a website without analyzing page code?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I catch DOMContentLoaded event. I have document that triggered the event. In the most cases the favicon can be obtained so:

```
let favicon=gBrowser.selectedTab.image;
```

But if page is rather big user can has time to activate other tab. In this case this code will obtain favicon of the new tab. I can obtain tab neighter for document nor for browser. Is it possible to obtain favicon without analyzing page code? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ajax the `favicon` directly from the site.

Comment: Other words is it impossible? I wouldn't like to use requests

Comment: No, not impossible. But then you would need to remember which tab was being loaded and when that has loaded get it via a firefox method, other than using the current selected tab (which I suspect is the problem).

Comment: Thank you. I thought the easier way exists

Answer (score 0):

yep use PlacesUtils, just use the domain name of the page, you don't have to wait for page to load to get that. get it from document.location

```
var {interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu} = Components;
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/PlacesUtils.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var uri = Services.io.newURI('http://www.bing.com/', null, null);

var callback = function(uri, len, data, mimeType) {
      alert(uri.spec);
      console.log(uri.spec);
}





PlacesUtils.favicons.getFaviconDataForPage(gBrowser.currentURI, callback );
```